# Stretching functionality of assignment operator in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen one of my professors use the assignment operator in C++ this way:

```
int valueOne;
int valueTwo;
valueOne = valueTwo = 0;
```

I wanted to start doing something similar in Objective-C but in this way:

```
@interface GameViewController () // Class extension in .m
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger pOneScore;
...
- (void)resetScore {
// Update singleton and local variable in one line using assignment operator
[[MySingleton sharedManager] setPlayerOneScore:pOneScore = 0];
…
```

.. and this seems to work. Can anyone see any potential dangers here? 
Other part of the question is: can I do this for objects as well? I assume in the case of objects, if it is possible, I will assign both pointers to the same memory location like this:

```
@interface GameViewController() // Class extension in .m
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *valueOne;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *valueTwo;
…
- (void)resetScore {
// Assign valueOne and valueTwo at the same time;
_valueOne = _valueTwo = @(0);
NSLog(@”valueOne = %@ and points to %p”, _valueOne, _valueOne);
NSLog(@”valueTwo = %@ and points to %p”, _valueTwo, _valueTwo);
…
```

I tested it and it seems to be OK, I wonder if there is any danger here. I look forward to any and all comments. Thanks

I am also wondering if the assignment operator can be utilized in similar ways in Java and C#.

Comment: The primary danger I see here is that it makes your code harder to read, without any real benefit. When you skim the code, it's very easy to miss the fact that there's an assignment statement in the `setPlayerOneScore:` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and works as you expected. Note that for objects you will, of course, always get the same instance and not a copy! That might be okay for `NSNumber`, but maybe not for other use cases.

Even if *some* people like using it, I generally don't recommend it, though. It makes the following two assignments look too similar:

```
valueOne = valueTwo = 0;
valueOne = valueTwo == 0;
```

Similarly:

```
[[MySingleton sharedManager] setPlayerOneScore:pOneScore = 0];
[[MySingleton sharedManager] setPlayerOneScore:pOneScore == 0];
```

The `==` type of statement is more common, which can make the other one look like someone forgot a character. That means I always have to verify what the author really meant. The same mechanism can be used to combine an assignment with an `if`, which is often considered similarly confusing.

That's why some modern languages (like Swift) went back on this and actually **don't** allow it.

Comment: I understand so far. I'm glad you mentioned (Swift) as well. Now, pOneScore == 0 , I guess will return a BOOL.

Comment: That would make sense, but it's not the case. It will just return `0` or `1`, because C didn't have a boolean type originally. (Swift does, so the Swift compiler will point out the error.)

Answer (score 0):

Personally

```
[[MySingleton sharedManager] setPlayerOneScore:pOneScore = 0];
```

looks a bit strange, and possibly error-prone for me, but

```
_valueOne = _valueTwo = @(0);
```

looks okay. I actually use this all the time (to save some typing, and IMO, it's fine to do anything as long as you know what you're doing). By the way, you don't need brackets in `@(0)` - just `@0` is sufficient.

Yes, you can do it in Java and C#.

**Good to know:** the reason why you can do this kind of assignment is because expressions like `a = 0` actually returns a value (which is `0` in this case), so `b = a = 0` is identical to `b = (a = 0)` (because assignment operator is right-associative).

In their new language Swift, Apple thinks this is a bad idea, so the behaviour was removed in Swift, and `a = 0` returns Void (which means returns nothing), and you can no longer do this "serial assignment" in Swift.